# SSRS background expression and null values issues

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in this [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe11H.png)
I would like to do this kind of background on SSRS dynamically, I thought to do the following condition:
= Iif (CInt (Fields! MoisBC.Value)> = CInt (Fields! MoisFact.Value), "Yellow", "PaleTurquoise")
it works but the condition does not apply to null values, [here is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aOcs.png) someone already experience this problem? thank you.

Comment: Is your expected result null cells be colored in `PaleTurquoise`? Avoid post an answer if it is not the solution to your problem, to provide feedback to anyone use comments instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding extra IIF condition to check NULL.

```
IIF(
   IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields! MoisBC.Value), 0, Fields! MoisBC.Value) >=
   IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields! MoisFact.Value), 0, Fields! MoisFact.Value)
, "Yellow"
, "PaleTurquoise")
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I just tested it but it does not change anything, I have the same result.